# How to validate SGML on OS X?

Tags: xml, macos, sgml

I have an SGML DTD (and related XML packet to go with it) that I need to validate.

How can I do this on OS X? It seems most XML tools don't 'get' SGML.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Perl library which parses both SGML and XML DTDs:

- [DTDParse](http://dtdparse.sourceforge.net/SGML-DTDParse/doc/html/lib/SGML/DTDParse.html)